# How to load WebView Progress bar without Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, webview

I found some sample source code which allows me to add a `ProgressView` when a `Webview` is loading in my app. However, the sample source code uses it with a `NavigationController`.

In my app I don't use a `NavigationController` I am just using a `UINavigatonBar` in the `Storyboard`

I have this code in `viewWillAppear` from the source code but it won't work in my app becuse it's referring to `NavigationController`

What would I need to change?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:_progressView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:_progressView];
```

you should use like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] addSubview: _progressView];
```